# How to account for optional arguments in Flask when rendering template

Tags: python, flask

I'm creating a basic search function to query columns in two different tables. If one column matches a given search term, it should render that template with the results and pass the arguments into the resulting html. If it matches both columns, it should pass the arguments into the resulting html. I want to be able to pass one or the other or both. The starting place is just a form that POSTS to this code:

```
@app.route('/search', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def search():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print "inside of request POST"
        search_term = request.form['search_term']
        poems = session.query(Poem).filter(Poem.name.contains(search_term)).all()
        authors = session.query(Author).filter(Author.name.contains(search_term)).all()

        if any(search_term in p.name for p in poems):
            print "found a poem!"
            if any(search_term in a.name for a in authors):
                print "found an author!"
                return render_template('results.html', poems=poems, authors=authors)
            else:
                print "only poems"
                return render_template('results.html', poems=poems)
        elif any(search_term in a.name for a in authors):
            print "only authors!"
            return render_template('results.html', authors=authors)
    else:
        print "in the last else"
        return render_template('search.html')
```

And here is what would be in the results.html:

```
<div id="container">

    {% for p in poems %}
    <div class="poem-title">{{p.name}}</div><br />
    {% endfor %}

    {% for a in authors %}
    <div class="author-title">{{a.name}}</div><br />
    {% endfor %}

</div>
```

One error I get is:

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1836, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app
response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1403, in handle_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request
return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
TypeError: results() takes no arguments (1 given)
```

Comment: Please post the full error traceback!

Comment: I posted it. It happens when I put an arbitrary value like 'a' as the search term which would result in a list of each object I believe... I could be wrong though.

Comment: Your traceback says you're calling `results()` but the code you posted is for `search()`

Comment: Welp. Looks like I just needed to restart the application. For some reason I think 'results' was in the flask package and wasn't my old 'results' method. I'm an idiot. Thanks!